# ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (5,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0), when adding my variables to my prediction machine

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction

I am creating a prediction machine with four variables. When I add the variables it all messes up and gives me:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (5,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)
```

code

```
       import pandas as pd
       from pandas import DataFrame
       from sklearn import linear_model
       import tkinter as tk 
       import statsmodels.api as sm
```

# Approach 1: Import the data into Python

```
Stock_Market = pd.read_csv(r'Training_Nis_New2.csv')
df = DataFrame(Stock_Market,columns=['Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 
4','Month 5','Month 6','Month 7','Month 8',
                                 'Month 9','Month 10','Month 11','Month 
12','FSUTX','MMUKX','FUFRX','RYUIX','Interest R','Housing 
Sale','Unemployement Rate','Conus Average Temperature 
Rank','30FSUTX','30MMUKX','30FUFRX','30RYUIX'])


X = df[['Month 1','Interest R','Housing Sale','Unemployement Rate','Conus Average Temperature Rank']] 
# here we have 2 variables for multiple regression. If you just want to use one variable for simple linear regression, then use X = df['Interest_Rate'] for example.Alternatively,  you may add additional variables within the brackets

Y = df[['30FSUTX','30MMUKX','30FUFRX','30RYUIX']]

# with sklearn
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)

print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)


# prediction with sklearn
# prediction with sklearn


HS=5.5
UR=6.7
CATR=8.9

New_Interest_R = 4.6



print('Predicted Stock Index Price: \n', regr.predict([[UR ,HS ,CATR 
,New_Interest_R]]))

# with statsmodel
X = df[['Month 1','Interest R','Housing Sale','Unemployement Rate','Conus Average Temperature Rank']]
Y = df['30FSUTX']
print('\n\n*** Fund = FSUTX')
X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant

model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X) 

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
```

Comment: Traceback please!  I can't tell where the error occurs.  It's the kind of error that a matrix multiplication would produce, `np.dot` or `@`, where the last dimension of `A` must match the 2nd to the last of `B`.

Comment: it says it occurs here '--> print('Predicted Stock Index Price: \n', regr.predict([[UR ,HS ,CATR ,New_Interest_R]]))'

Comment: Is that all it says?

Comment: The problem probably lies with the mix of dimensions of the `X`, `Y` and `predict` argument.  One is 5 columns of the dataframe, the other 4, and the last a (1,4) array (list) of scalars.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dc4ab16cc3e1> in <module>
     37 
     38 
---> 39 print('Predicted Stock Index Price: \n', regr.predict([[UR ,HS ,CATR ,New_Interest_R]]))
     40 
     41 # with statsmodel

Comment: so should i have 5 variables instead of 4?